# Setting property on large number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm hitting a `OutOfMemoryError` when trying to set a property for a large number of nodes in Neo4j using cypher.

The approach I'm using is like this:

```
MATCH (n:MYLABEL) SET n.num_visits = 0 RETURN count(n)
```

This works OK when the number of nodes matched is in the 100,000s range, but when it get to the millions of nodes range I hit the OutOfMemoryError problem after a very long delay.
What is the best approach to handle this without memory problems and to get the operation to complete relatively quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`apoc.periodic.iterate`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) procudere from the [`APOC library`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). For example:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate (
  "MATCH (n:MYLABEL) RETURN n",
  "SET n.num_visits = 0", 
  {
     batchSize: 100000, 
     parallel: true
  }
)
```